# Errors while creating pool using indy-cli

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, decentralized-identity, indy-node

I have ran the indy_pool network and it is up using the command : docker run -itd -p 9701-9708:9701-9708 indy_pool

Now, I have installed indy-cli in my system

Now when I am trying to create a pool using the command:
pool create local_pool gen_text_file=/<PATH_TO_INDY_SDK>/indy-sdk/cli/docker_pool_transactions_genesis

It is giving me the error :
Unknown "gen_text_file" parameter present

Can someone explain why is this issue coming and what can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give right path in "/<PATH_TO_INDY_SDK>" variable so that it can target "[docker_pool_transactions_genesis](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/cli/docker_pool_transactions_genesis)" file.

To know the path of indy-sdk, go to the folder where you give "docker run -itd -p 9701-9708:9701-9708 indy_pool" command and run "echo $PWD" command.

Suppose I clone the indy-sdk into my Ubuntu home, so my gen_text_file path is "/home/indy-sdk/cli/docker_pool_transactions_genesis "

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.14.1 and later of indy-cli, the parameter you need is actually gen_txn_file=

Here is a copy of the "help":

```
> pool create help 
Command:
    pool create - Create new pool ledger config with specified name

Usage:
    pool create <name-value> gen_txn_file=<gen_txn_file-value>

Parameters are:
    name - The name of new pool ledger config
    gen_txn_file - Path to file with genesis transactions

Examples:
    pool create pool1 gen_txn_file=/home/pool_genesis_transactions
```